# How to keep C# interfaces organized?

Tags: c#, architecture

I am working as part of the team on the web api application. The Entity Framework used as ORM, I have the idea to keep all selectors in services. E.g. we have `Cat` table, then would be `CatSelectorsService`.

```
class CatSelectorsService {
    public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
        return it => it.LastTimePlayed > date;
    }

    public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() {
        var needToPlay = NeedToPlay();
        return it => new CatView {
            Id = it.Id,
            NeedToPlay = needToPlay.Invoke(it)
        }
    }
}

// sample usage
var catViews = context.Cats.Select(catSelectosService.CatView());
var catIdsNeedToPlay = context.Cats.Where(catSelectorsService.NeedToPlay()).Select(it => it.Id);
```

That approach really helps to avoid code duplication and help organize business logic of the application. Initially was planning to have exactly one selectors service per entity. So, CatSelectorsService

- Cat - entity name
- Selectors - what class handles
- Service - can be recived via constructor DI from interface, e.g.

```
    public MyClass {
        private readonly ICatSelectorsService catSelectorsService;
        public MyClass(ICatSelectorsService catSelectorsService) {
            this.catSelectorsService = catSelectorsService;
        }
    }
```

Good organization. On practice have meet two issues with this approach:

1. Circular depencies, when some selectors want to use other selectors, f.e. if have Cats and Users, we might want to the next inside selectors service

```
    // inside cats selectors service
    public Expressions<Func<Cat, CatView>> CatView() {
        return it => new CatView {
            Users = it.Users.Select(userSelectorsService.UserView()), // here reference userSelectors in catSelectors
        }
    }
    
    // inside users selectors service
    public Expressions<Func<User, UserViewWithCats>> UserView() {
        return it => new CatView {
            Users = it.Users.Select(catSelectorsService.CatView()), // here reference catSelectors in userSelectors
        }
    }
```

current solution to create shared selectors and reference them, e.g.

```
public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView>> CatView() => sharedSelectors.CatView(); // shared selectors can be imported in other services
```

2. Testing, in the first sample, I'll copy it to here:

```
    class CatSelectorsService {
        public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() {
            var date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
            return it => it.LastTimePlayed > date;
        }
    
        public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() {
            var needToPlay = NeedToPlay();
            return it => new CatView {
                Id = it.Id,
                NeedToPlay = needToPlay.Invoke(it)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // sample usage
    var catViews = context.Cats.Select(catSelectosService.CatView());
    var catIdsNeedToPlay = context.Cats.Where(catSelectorsService.NeedToPlay()).Select(it => it.Id);
```

`CatView` uses `NeedToPlay` when writing tests for cat selectors, I want to mock `NeedToPlay`, but to do it with xunit, I have to move `NeedToPlay` to separate service. Or use some workaround like harmony, I have tried harmony, and it is works, however it also make the ecosystem of the application harder and I'd like to keep it simple. Harmony for unit testing is rather advanced library - some issues with running in parallel. So ended with next:

```
class SharedSelectorsService {
    public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
        return it => it.LastTimePlayed > date;
    }

    public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() {
        var needToPlay = NeedToPlay();
        return it => new CatView {
            Id = it.Id,
            NeedToPlay = needToPlay.Invoke(it)
        }
    }
}

class CatSelectorsService {
    private readonly ISharedSelectorsService sharedSelectorsService;

    public CatSelectorsService(ISharedSelectorsService sharedSelectorsService) {
        this.sharedSelectorsService = sharedSelectorsService;
    }

    public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() => sharedSelectorsService.NeedToPlay()
    public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() => sharedSelectorsService.CatView();
}
```

I don't like that finally have lot of services, and one them is just a documentation(`CatSelectorsService`), to keep things organized, but for me it seems currently the best solution. However I really wonder, can be something better?

PS. Also have thought about creating the documentation, but I have not experience and seems to me that self documentated the code cheaper then support of actual version of documenation.

#### Update - why want to mock the `NeedToPlay`

Here hidden two features:

1. Cat view
2. Cat need to play

We have separate tests for `Cat View` and tests for `need to play`. Should we change `cat view` tests each time `cat need to play` feature changed? Should we setup data of `Need to play` in the `Cat view`? For me yes looks like an illustration of interface segregation principle violation.

Comment: @DocBrown: "a whole bunch of hard-to-read boilerplate code" - actually, it's perhaps unfamiliar, but once you get over that, it's not hard to read at all, and it's not boilerplate code, it's business logic (it's really a variant of the Specification pattern (which is, BTW, not described very well on Wikipedia, which focuses eclusively on a composite-based variant of it)). Each of these methods returns a spec of what to select from the data context (e.g. `NeedToPlay` returns a specification that describes when are cats considered in need of play). Besides, what's hard-to-read is team-specific.

Comment: P.S. In the sense that if the team is used to thinking in these terms, it's not hard-to-read for them (they'll just gloss over the `Expression<Func<____, ____>` bit). If that's the case, they should leverage their way of thinking and associated abstractions even if the code may seem at first a bit opaque to a general audience, because they are not writing for a general audience - they are the ones who will be reading the code most of the time.

Comment: @DocBrown: Well, I wrote this primarily for the benefit of the OP (as I didn't want them to be too quick to abandon their idea based on a single negative comment), even though I'm addressing you. Also, I thought it was appropriate to mention you out of respect and out of courtesy, given that I'm contending your point of view.

Comment: @DocBrown - Yes, I would like to hear some feedback from the OP too, but since this is work-related, and it's the weekend, maybe it'll take a day or so.

Comment: @ Nikita: I'd also be interested to hear why do you feel the need to mock NeedToPlay? At first glance, there doesn't seem to be a good reason for that.

Comment: The view logic abstraction seems to me like a reinvented mapper. Is there a reason you're not e.g. just using Automapper and instead reinventing that wheel?

Comment: @Flater I have not been using it previously, however my colleague had said, that he had some issues with it. Currently, all the expressions can be translated to SQL from Linq to SQL, combined via LinqKit, and `expressionsService.Combine`, also it is perfomant, as queries only neccessary data from the database, and less bugs produced as not need to write `Include` at all.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović updated question, added the answer

Comment: @DocBrown updated question, added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments under the question. As mentioned by Filip in the comments, it is for Specification. Also often some selectors can be reused. F.e. `NeedToPlay` can be used in the validation, and in some views.

So, after weekends, and some playing with code, the thing have been understood, the unit of work for developer is smth like implemented feature. So here to different features `CatView` and `CatNeedsToPlay` under one business domain, so they should be placed on separate services.

```
// service per feature
class CatNeedToPlaySelectorsService : ICatNeedsToPlaySelectorsService {
    public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
        return it => it.LastTimePlayed > date;
    }
}
 
// service per feature
class CatViewSelectorsService : ICatViewSelectorsService {
    private readonly ICanNeedToPlaySelectorsService catNeedToPlaySelectorsService;
    public CatViewSelectorsService() {
        this.catNeedToPlaySelectorsService = catNeedToPlaySelectorsService;
    }
 
    public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() {
        var needToPlay = catNeedToPlaySelectorsService.NeedToPlay();
        return it => new CatView {
            Id = it.Id,
            NeedToPlay = needToPlay.Invoke(it)
        }.Expand(); // see LinqKit library
    }
}
 
// {EntityName}SelectorsService to keep organized
class CatSelectorsService : ICatSelectorsService {
    private readonly ICanNeedToPlaySelectorsService catNeedToPlaySelectorsService;
    private readonly ICatViewSelectorsService catViewSelectorsService;
    public CatSelectorsService(ICanNeedToPlaySelectorsService catNeedToPlaySelectorsService, ICatViewSelectorsService catViewSelectorsService) {
        this.catNeedToPlaySelectorsService = catNeedToPlaySelectorsService;
        this.catViewSelectorsService = catViewSelectorsService;
    }
     
    public Expression<Func<Cat, CatView> CatView() => this.catViewSelectorsService.CatView();
    public Expressions<Func<Cat, bool>> NeedToPlay() => this.catNeedToPlaySelectorsService.NeedToPlay();
}
```

1. Much less merge conflicts, as every developer working on its own feature in the separate file, not in the same file
2. Simpler tests - no redundant setups, services are easy to mock with widely used `Mock<T>`
3. No redundant dependencies, f.e. if need some service only for `CatView` it would be imported only to `CatView` without effect on `NeedToPlay`

**Conclusion**, it is nice (independent of development language) when features are located in separate files, as separation on different files really minifies merged conflicts amount and simplify writing of unit tests. Also it is more comfortable to look over one small file then over one big file. However in this case need some way to organize all the files, f.e. group on folders or some other way.

PS. The `NeedsToPlay.Invoke(it)` made by LinqKit library

PPS. Also have written the `ExpressionsService` for case when selectors can be combined, please put comment if need the code of `ExpressionsService`

```
listItem = it => new { it.Id, it.Name }
// next is the same as: detailsItem = it => new { it.Id, id.Name, it.Details };
detailsItem = expressionsService.Combine(listItem, it => new { it.Details });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CatSelectorsService` is mixing two very different things:

- Filters (i.e. `Func<T, bool>`), used for getting a subset of items
- Mappings (i.e `Func<T, TargetType>`), used to convert items from one to the other

These are two things that are quite different from one another, and each have a (different) home already, but you've instead housed them together in `CatSelectorsService`. This feels forced to me.

**Filters** are essentially queries, and should be structured as such. There are varied ways of doing so. You could house them in specific repositories (e.g. `CatRepository`), or you could be using actual query objects or CQRS (e.g. `GetCatsForPlayingQuery`).

Your selector service stores the query logic, but not the actual data retrieval. I don't see the purpose in separating these in this way, as a query is essentially comprised of both. I'm not saying you can't promote reusability here, but having a flipbook of filter logic isn't particularly useful and takes more overhead than it's worth.

**Mappings** are notably different from queries, and while queries can incorporate a mapping, there is value to keeping mappings separate as the likelihood of substituting/reusing mappings across queries is something that will render you benefits.

Based on your current use case, I see no reason to not use Automapper here. It provides all the features you need, in a much more streamlined process. Especially when you consider [`.ProjectTo<TTargetType>()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html), you can see how much cleaner this same approach can be done.

In short, the idea of separating your mappings from your queries is good, but the implementation can be done a lot cleaner than it currently is being done. I suggest either using Automapper (or any equivalent mapping library), or at least taking a page from their book on how you can manage the mappings in a clean and readable fashion.

> On practice have meet two issues with this approach:

> 1. Circular depencies, when some selectors want to use other selectors, f.e. if have Cats and Users, we might want to the next inside selectors service

If your concern is about the instantiation of the services; then circular dependencies aren't an issue if your dependencies are registered as anything but transient. Transient circular dependencies will cause a stack overflow, but scoped or singleton dependencies will not (since the same instance will be reused in the dependency graph).

If your concern is that you run into an infinite loop when fetching an actual query from the service, then there's a problem with how you're expecting these separate queries to interact. That's not inherently caused by circular dependency injection, but rather with actually circularly depending on your own logic.

Circular dependencies *can* be valid, but they need to be handled carefully. Whether you choose to take close care, or instead outright avoid doing it in the first place, is both your decision and very contextual.

> 2. Testing

As I mentioned, splitting queries from their mappings has their purpose, but when testing, you're generally going to want to test the whole query. That includes the data fetching, filtering, and mapping. At least, when the mapping is part of the actual query (which is the case when you use Automapper's `ProjectTo`).

If the mapping is a separate step that is only done after the query has been executed, then you should indeed test the query and the mapping separately.

Though in my experience across several companies, mapping tests are commonly avoided as they're an exercise in duplication, since the test body itself is pretty much describing the mapping again. Mappings *are* tested as part of the output of a e.g. a query (or query service), but mappings themselves are not tested in isolation (other than Automapper's `AssertConfigurationIsValid`).

Whether you choose to do this isolated mapping testing or not is up to you. There are arguments pro and con.

Comment: Yes, like the word projection here more then mapping) `select Name, Id from Users where UserId = 1` here `Name, Id` is a projection of `Users where UserId = 1`, the selectors are located separately as they are used on with different sources, and sometime they even can be combined, e.g. `select Name, Id from Users where UserId = 1` and `select Name, Id, Age from Users where UserId = 1` base projection `name, id` and extended `name, id, age`. Or when one projection use another, see how CatView use NeedToPlay in my answer. Have used word `selector` as it often used in linq `.Select()`

Comment: I will take a look to Automapper at free time, however, I skeptical about this lib in my use-case)) because it maps objects, not manage expressions (`it => new { it.Id}` is an expression), so possibly it would be not as flexible and perfomant as I wish with `linq-to-sql`. Very possible Automapper good solution to map in-memory objects.

Comment: "you're generally going to want to test the whole query" you are absolutely right) we have  one general integration test per each query to ensure the resulting linq-query translate to sql and runs on the database. And unit tests for mappings just to cover some edge cases, f.e. sometimes the selector can be used as mapper, e.g. `CatView.Compile()(cat)` then it would be `linq-to-objects` and some other from `linq-to-sql` rules would play here

Comment: @Nikita: `it => new { it.Id}` Anonymous types have their use, but I would advise against them for actual query results. This is a situation in which you definitely want to be using a named type for documentative purposes. I think your system enables overuse of anonymous types in this way.

Comment: no anonymous, usually: `selector = it => new SomeView { }`

Comment: @Nikita `new SomeView` is still a new object, just like what Automapper does for you behind the scenes. You don't see the instantiation happening but it does. Secondly, Automapper actually plays _very_ nice with linq-to-sql when using projectto.

Comment: want to add  "I'm not saying you can't promote reusability here", that for me it is also helps to remember the business requirement when looking over the code some weeks later, e.g. like some kind of specification

Comment: about automapper here the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503827/linq-to-sql-and-auto-mapper in the answert virtual views suggested but from experience I avoid them, as they are not under the source control, as ef models, it is difficult with time to manage them, however have no problems with expressions and don't need views. Then posted that they have added this, but I afraid of meeting smth similar, as was with my colleague)

Comment: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Comment: @Nikita: The linked SO question is **9 years old** and predates Automapper's ProjectTo feature, as well as _many_ EF improvements since then.

Comment: @Nikita: Also, the answer that focuses on using views is effectively arguing to use views _instead of_ automapper; which is not an issue _with_ using Automapper, but a way to _not_ use Automapper. I agree with your reasoning why you wouldn't want to use views, but that doesn't say anything about supposed issues with using Automapper.